# How to close accordion after refreshing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Accordion open after refresh] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Qwr.png)

If I refresh my browser the accordion is expanding automatically, If I click any one accordion it shrinks.

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accordion h1").click(function(){
        var id = this.id;   /* getting heading id */
    
        /* looping through all elements which have class .accordion-content */
        $(".accordion-content").each(function(){
    
            if($("#"+id).next()[0].id != this.id){
                $(this).slideUp();
            }   
    
        });
    
        $(this). next(). toggle();  /* Selecting div after h1 */
    });
    });
```

Expectation is, If I refresh all the accordions should shrink.

Comment: `$(".accordion h1").trigger('click');`

Comment: Without knowing your HTML and CSS, a quick and dirty fix can be what bassxzero recommended - you would wrap that inside `$(document).ready(...)`. A more stable solution would be to understand ***why*** are the tabs expanded. Open your document inspector, and see what changes in your tabs when you keep clicking on them, and triggering the expanding / collapsing. If there's a class which is being added on `collapse`, just add that class to your tabs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your html logic, but I suggest that you use jQuery `toggleClass`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accordion h1").click(function(){
            
        $(this). next(). toggleClass("accordion-content");  /* Selecting div after h1 */
    });
 });
```

```css
.accordion-content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <h1 id="tab_1">tab 1</h1>
  <div attr_id="tab_1" class="accordion-content1">
  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
  <h1 id="tab_1">tab 2</h1>
  <div attr_id="tab_1" class="accordion-content1">
  
  </div>
</div>
```